# Anti-derivative of a function involving exponentially distributed variable

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, improper-integrals

Suppose a random variable $x$ with p.d.f $f(x) = \lambda e^{-\lambda x}$ such that $\lambda$ is the parameter of $f$. Given a function $ g(x) = (a + bx )e^{- \frac{\lambda x}{a}} $ where $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$,  I would like to simplify
$$ \int_0^{\infty}g(x)f(x)dx = \int_0^{\infty}g(x)\lambda e^{-\lambda x}dx $$

I do not know how to integrate this expression.